# Stop SQL Server 2008 R2 from listing databases for users without access

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is there a way to stop MS SQL Server listing databases for a user which does not have access to those databases? At the moment if I setup a user on database A I can still see database B, C, D, E and so on, although I do not have permissions access them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All SQL logins are members of the 'public' server-level role, which by default has the [VIEW ANY DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189077.aspx) permission.
This will revoke that permission :

```
REVOKE VIEW ANY DATABASE FROM public
```

Comment: This removes the view database from the required login also. Is there a way so the user can still at least see there own database?

Comment: From the page you gave: "To limit visibility to database metadata, deny a login the VIEW ANY DATABASE permission. After this permission is denied, a login can see only metadata for master, tempdb, and databases that the login owns. " this means I should be able to see the database as the user is db_owner against the assigned login. Do is there anything else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Is the login in question the actual owner of the database or just a member of db_owner? ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::<DBNAME> TO <DBOWNERLOGIN> should make them explicitly the owner. If they're not the actual owner then they can't see it in SSMS. This is a known limitation as mentioned here : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/bac3cf1f-65bc-4340-84ac-5fdd4b9d71cd